# How to find full or Nill or partial Present of table in other table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Create table #Table1  (id int)
Create table #Table2  (id int)

--Table1 insertion
insert into #Table1(id) values (5)
insert into #Table1(id) values (1)
insert into #Table1(id) values (2)

--Table2 insertion
insert into #Table2(id) values (5)
insert into #Table2(id) values (6)
insert into #Table2(id) values (7)
```

I Want to evaluate three conditions:

1. whether `Table1` is fully present in `Table2`
2. `Table1` is not completely present in `Table2` (intersection is nothing)
3. `Table1` is partially present in `Table2`.

How can I do this?

Comment: School work? Do you really think you'll learn anything if we do the work for you?

Comment: Hint. Do a left join and check for nulls.

Comment: just look at `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` AND `RIGHT JOIN` sql structures

Comment: Alternatively EXISTS, NOT EXISTS, INTERSECT etc.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
begin tran

Create table #Table1  (id int)
Create table #Table2  (id int)

--Table1 insertion
insert into #Table1(id) values (5)
insert into #Table1(id) values (1)
insert into #Table1(id) values (2)

--Table2 insertion
insert into #Table2(id) values (5)
insert into #Table2(id) values (6)
insert into #Table2(id) values (7)

select case when exists (
    select 1
    from #Table1 t1
    where not exists(select 1 from #Table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
) then 0 else 1 end as Table1IsFullyInTable2

select case when exists (
    select 1
    from #Table1 t1
    where not exists(select 1 from #Table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
) then 1 else 0 end as Table1DoesNotExistFullyInTable2

select case when exists (
    select 1
    from #Table1 t1
    where exists(select 1 from #Table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
) then 1 else 0 end as Table1ParitiallyInTable2

rollback tran
```